# How to scan through an array and do something once it catches a certain phrase

Tags: c, argv, argc

In C, suppose I need the code to do something when the user enters something like "-o" in the command line of linux involving argv and argc. More specifically if the file name starts with -o. How do I catch when a specific character string is entered?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == 'o')
        {
            /* "-o" detected. Take care of argv[i] here. */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use getopt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[]) {
    char *file;
    int opt;
    while ( ( opt = getopt(argc, argv, "o:") ) != -1 ){
        switch(opt){
        case 'o':
            file=strdup(optarg);
            printf("file is %s\n", file);
            free(file);
            break;
        default :
            ;//return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
/* demo
>a.out -o test.c
file is test.c
*/
```